# Azure Powershell Function Response as CSV

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I'm making an Azure Function App which will return csv data to the caller.

I'm trying to understand how best to insert the csv values into the reponse body. Here is a fragment of code which I am working with:

```
if ($firstName -and $lastName) {
    $body = @()
    $body += "first,last"
    $body += "$firstName,$lastName"
} else { $body = '{ "status": "snarled" }' }


# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    ContentType = "text/csv; charset=utf-8"
    Body = $body
})
```

The issue here though is that this instead of just returning the strings it returns them inside '[' and ']' which I suppose makes sense given its an array. So here is what I am getting back:

```
["first,last","joe,soap"]
```

What I am trying to get back is:

```
first,last
joe,soap
```

How should I format the $body to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a single string rather than an array:

```
if ($firstName -and $lastName) {
    $body = @"
first,last
$firstName,$lastName
"@
} else { $body = '{ "status": "snarled" }' }
```

... or:

```
if ($firstName -and $lastName) {
    $body = [pscustomobject]@{first = $firstName; last = $lastName} |ConvertTo-Csv
} else { $body = '{ "status": "snarled" }' }
```

Comment: Fantastic. The pscustomobject method is excellent as it double quotes the values and headers. Ideal! Thank you very much.